# AWS Multiple Lambda Functions in one zip

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I'm using CloudFormation to create lambda resources and I have several python scripts as well as one js script in a `lambda-resources` folder. Would it be okay to pass the same file location for every lambda function and just specify unique handlers? When my lambda function is created it looks like it only creates one lambda function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely one way to accomplish what you're looking to do.

You'll need to create a zipped version of your `lambda-resources` folder and [upload it via the Lambda service](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3100/how-do-i-upload-my-zipped-lambda-code-into-aws-lambda) or even to S3, then reference it as the file location for each Lambda function.

Comment: okay great this is what I thought! Turns out one of the resources was blocking the creation of the other functions so it looked like they weren't being created,